# Get a dictionary of sorted keys from comparisons across a dictionary of 2D arrays

Tags: python

Say I have a dictionary `my_dict` holding several 2D numpy arrays (one per key). All these arrays have of the same dimensions. Let's assume we have 1000 such arrays.

I would like to obtain a dictionary `top_per_location` where, given a tuple `(x,y)`, `top_per_location[(x,y)]` returns the tuple of keys in `my_dict` sorted by the value of `my_dict[key][x,y]`.

The brute force approach to this (i.e. looping explicitly for every `[x,y]`for every key in dict) seems very slow. Any ideas on how to solve this without looping explicitly?

So far I have:

```
# xsize and ysize are the 
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:xsize, 0:ysize]
top_per_location = dict()
for x,y in zip(grid_x.ravel(), grid.y_ravel):
    values = dict()
    for key in my_dict:
      values[key] = my_dict[key][x,y]
    # We would then sort values[key]
    # and store the sorted keys in top_per_location[(x,y)]
```

to **just loop through every key**, and this takes a long time for `xsize=ysize=100`

Comment: How many of these will you need to query?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I updated my post. Let's assume 20 arrays.

Comment: Oh, if only 20, @Brionius' answer is probably more applicable than mine. If you have *lots* of data, consider changing your data structure to take advantage of numpy's vectorisation features.

Answer (score 2):

If it's speed you're after, you're probably better off with a different data structure to begin with. Make a 3D array of data `n*y*x` and a 1D array of keys with the index of the keys matching the n_index of the data array. This way we can vectorise.

In an abstract sense:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(10 * 5 * 5).reshape((10, 5, 5))
numpy.random.shuffle(a)
b = numpy.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
print b[numpy.argsort(a[:, 3, 3])]
```

Applied you your current data structure:

```
# Simulating my_dict
y_dim = 5
x_dim = 6
my_dict = {chr(i + 97): numpy.random.randn(y_dim, x_dim) for i in xrange(10)}

# To initially convert your data structure
new_my_dict = {}
keys = numpy.zeros(len(my_dict), dtype=numpy.str)
data = numpy.zeros((len(my_dict), y_dim, x_dim))
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(my_dict.iteritems()):
    keys[i] = key
    data[i, :, :] = value
    new_my_dict[key] = i


# the sorting function
def top_per_location(y, x):
    return keys[numpy.argsort(data[:, y, x])]

def get_data(key):
    index = new_my_dict.get(key)
    if index is not None:
        return data[index]
    else:
        raise KeyError('{} not in data!'.format(key))

def add_data(key, new_data):
    global data, keys
    if key in new_my_dict:
        data[new_my_dict[key]] = new_data
    else:
        new_my_dict[key] = data.shape[0] + 1
        keys = numpy.append(keys, key)
        data = numpy.concatenate((data, numpy.expand_dims(new_data, axis=0)))

print(top_per_location(3, 3))
add_data('frog', numpy.random.randn(y_dim, x_dim))
add_data('fish', numpy.random.randn(y_dim, x_dim))
print(get_data('frog'))
```

You can still have your dictionary, if you need to do lots of lookups, but make it a simple {key: index} dictionary, there the index points to the n_dimension of your data.

Answer (score 1):

How about a function rather than a dictionary?

```
def top_per_location(xy):
    return tuple(sorted(my_dict.keys(), key=lambda key:my_dict[key][xy]))
```

Example usage:

```
top_per_location((2, 3))
```

That should return a tuple of keys sorted by the value at coordinates (x, y) in each array.

Whether this is more efficient than your dictionary solution depends how often you're going to *use* the dictionary vs. how often you're going to have to *create* the dictionary.

Note:  That assumes `my_dict` is accessible from the function namespace.  If it isn't, you'll need to do something like pass `my_dict` in as an argument.